# Set up a virtual machine (with ssh access) without installing a GUI

Tags: macos, virtual-machine

I'd like to set up a linux environment on a local Virtual Machine to test/develop code before running it on a cluster. I don't need or want a GUI on the VM as all the work I need it for will be command-line based.

What is the best way to set up a VMWare Linux virtual machine with ssh access, without installing a GUI? Ideally the VM would be as light-weight as possible to minimise the impact on the host Mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't quite tell but I assume you want the guest host to not have a GUI (gnome, kde, etc), so just download whatever distro (I like Ubuntu) and install their server version, which doesn't have a GUI.

Answer (score 4):

[Virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org) is a fast easy to use virtualization application.  You can use the [headless mode](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#vboxheadless) to run the virtual machine without a GUI.

Answer (score 1):

For the guest, I use Ubuntu [JeOS](http://www.ubuntu.com/products/whatisubuntu/serveredition/jeos), which stands for "Just enough OS". It is an installation option specifically for VMs.

And I use [VMware Server](http://www.vmware.com/products/server/), which is free (as is beer) for the VMware host.

Comment: But VMWare Server isn't available for MacOS X.